# Why are there black lines on my seamless texture?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I edited a seamless texture in affinity photo and added it to a spherical object. However, when I zoom in on the texture there are very thin black lines.
[image]

I cannot see any lines on the texture image itself:[image]

Comment: On the texture they might not be visible and it's hard to see on the white background here, but to the right and bottom there is a single bright line. In the screenshot the line is dark, not bright - but the _Image Texture_ node says it's a PNG, not a JPG which you uploaded here. So presumably the PNG has a semi-transparent vertical and horizontal line on the border, which shows dark on a darker background. In the JPG the transparency cannot be stored and I guess there the background is set to white, that's why it looks brighter in the uploaded image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those one-pixel lines at the right and bottom edges of the image become visible if you zoom in enough: [image]